# Allow non-root user to use timedatectl

Tags: debian, permissions, systemd, date

I have a small Linux device that *may* choose to sync it's time with a handheld device when said device connects to it. My program's been running as root, and I've just been using `date --set` commands. But I'm trying to move said program to a less privileged user. Since I'm using `systemd` now, I think I should be using `timedatectl` to set the time rather than date directly. I've proven to myself how I can do this root. But I don't know how to drive it from non-root.

I could use a specific sudo item, but I was hoping to not have my program running sudo. If that's the only way though, I know how to do that. If that's the only way, then just answer that :)

I hoped that if I made my user a member of the `systemd-timesync` group, I might be able to, but with or without said group, I get the following error:

```
> timedatectl set-time "2017-3-2 01:40:30"
Failed to set time: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
```

I have no idea what that means, or how to fix it, or if I should, or if it's possible.

Comment: Have you got *policykit-1* installed?

Comment: You could try using `ACL` permissions - either specifically for the user or a user group allowed to run the program. Make sure to mount the partition with `ACL`s then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `sudo`. You express reluctance to that approach, but you would only be granting your user root access to run the single `timedatectl` command.

This *ought* be able to be solved with PolicyKit as well, but it would effectively have the same result of allowing a user to run a single command as root. So the risks would be similar-- and you already understand how to solve the problem with `sudo`.

Comment: some additional context: It is not sudo by default that allows you to give access to timedatectl in a secure way. What Mark means is that a correctly configured sudoers allows you to use timedatectl securely, by hard coded the command and set-time argument.
Also polkit may not be enabled in all systems, and although configuring polkit will get you closer to the actual semantics of what you want to do, in practical terms you will get the same results and no different security. I wrote about this topic in https://cenains.blog/2021/08/31/sudo-in-system/